# How do I get the selected tab in a workbook (but not the ActiveWorkbook)?

Tags: excel, vba

I hope this is a simple question...

My understanding is that "ActiveWorkbook" returns the currently active workbook, even if the macro was run in a different workbook (this is why I almost always use "ThisWorkbook" instead).

And "ActiveSheet" returns the currently active worksheet, even if the macro was run in a different workbook (or different worksheet).

So how can I get the worksheet which currently has focus within a specific workbook, even if that workbook is not the currently active one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by fully qualifying `.ActiveSheet`

Example:

```
Private Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add

    'Change the name of Sheet1 in the second workbook
    'so it's not confused with Sheet1 in the first workbook.
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Foo"

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    MsgBox wb.ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I knew it would be something simple. Just out of idle curiosity, what would be the full qualification of the default behavior? ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet? Application.ActiveSheet?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` for the workbook that the vba module is in. `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` for the currently active workbook, even if it is not `ThisWorkbook`. `Application.ActiveSheet` is essentially the same as `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`

Comment: `Thisworkbook` is the book that the VBA is actually in, `ActiveWorkbook` is the book that currently has focus.